# How to get a versionName in react-native app on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I've made a timestamped versionName in build.gradle like 20150707.1125.  I want to show the version of the package in react-native app in about window. How I could get versionName in code?

Comment: May it works? https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I've successfully used the [React Native Device Info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) component to get the build details as specified in the Gradle config.

Once installed you can use:

```
DeviceInfo.getVersion()
```

To output the version, and:

```
DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber()
```

To get the build number.

Comment: It's a big package with useless `gcm` need! I removed it from my project.

Comment: I would downvote the deviceInfo too. My story is I integrated the react-native-firebase and got it work in android. after that, I installed this react-native-device-info and it seems to work fine in android. Except what AlirezaXX said, it's real a big package and took a long time to install. The nightmare came to the IOS part. I use podfile to install firebase and no matter how, it always fails to build. I google the error code and find lots of "solutions" that didn't work for me. The worst part is that I didn't even know the deviceInfo link is the culprit.

Comment: until early this morning 5:30AM, I got it works but very mad to also find react-native-device-info is the bad guy. and the solution i found somewhere else that works for me is also here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/63

Comment: There is a method DeviceInfo.getReadableVersion() that will give you a single string containing both the version and build number. Perhaps this didn't exist when the answer was originally written. Source: https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getreadableversion states "Gets the application human readable version (same as getVersion() + '.' + getBuildNumber())"

Answer (score 91):

If you want the version number in your package.json, you can also do:

```
var pkg = require('./package.json');
console.log(pkg.version);
```

Comment: this is the easiest solution, without installing any module

Comment: FYI "package is a reserved word in strict mode"

Comment: and then automate versioning using npm version like this: https://medium.com/@andr3wjack/versioning-react-native-apps-407469707661

Comment: i am getting "package is a reserved word in strict mode" .what to do ?

Comment: Used `const appJson = require('../app.json')` then `<Text>Version: {appJson.expo.version}</Text>` in my [Expo](https://expo.io/) app. Worked a charm.

Comment: This will include your whole package json inside of your app. **Any** person can read that in the final bundle.
it will also not reflect the native version string, which may vary depending on various factors (mine is flavors prefixes)
it will also include a lot of unneeded infos (and perhaps a lib for that will occupy less space in the final app)

Comment: Apparently this is a bit of a security risk since you are exposing all of your dependencies. As well, you are loading the entirety of `package.json` just to fetch the `version`. I would recommend using something like `import { version } from "./package.json"` if your project allows you to.

Comment: but every time i have to edit the package json (app version).

Answer (score 65):

The right answer:

```
DeviceInfo.getVersion();
```

If you want to get it from your package.json:

```
import { version } from './package.json';
```

Comment: the question is about how to read it from build.gradle file not from package.json

Answer (score 21):

I couldn't get the package `react-native-device-info` to work. Ran into [this issue](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/236) Might need some gradle and java changes to make it fly.

Anyhow I got what I needed [`react-native-version-number`](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-version-number). And I am happy with it.

```
import VersionNumber from 'react-native-version-number';

console.log('appVersion:', VersionNumber.appVersion)
```

Oh, and as it relates to gleaning the version from `package.json`. It feels wrong to me. I mean I had to try it just to see if it would work. I didn't realize that resource would be available at runtime on the device. It does work, but I also have some buildTypes debug foo going on in my build.gradle I learned [here](https://medium.com/@manas/manage-your-android-app-s-versioncode-versionname-with-gradle-7f9c5dcf09bf). So its nice to be getting the `versionName` like `0.1.7-debug` straight from the horses mouth.

Comment: This is not working for iOS, It is working for Android only.

Comment: Works for both Android + iOS for me.

Comment: Showing null value in Android

Comment: Make sure you are rebuilding your project after installing if you get null values.

Answer (score 9):

I used as reference the answer by [@Marcos Demetrio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6923117/marcos-dem%C3%A9trio)

But I was using expo, so I did this:

```
import {expo} from '../../app.json'
```

And in the Component:

```
<Label>{expo.version}</Label>
```

No package install needed.

Comment: Ha!  Very smart.

Comment: Although FYI - the expo recommended way would be to use the Constants api.  https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#versioning-your-app

Comment: the question is about how to read it from `build.gradle` file not from app.json

Answer (score 9):

You can use [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getversion)

And you can get app version for both iOS and Android by calling following method.

```
const version = DeviceInfo.getVersion();

// iOS: "1.0"
// Android: "1.0"
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have Android versionName as "2.0.1". Still, it shows, "2.0"

Comment: @KushalDesai third number is buildNumber, not app version :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using expo and you want lighter lib, use [expo-application](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/application/):

```js
import * as Application from 'expo-application';

Application.nativeApplicationVersion //returns a string
// or
Application.nativeBuildVersion //returns a string
```

Comment: I received incorrect version number for some reason with expo-application

Answer (score 2):

react-native-version-number library works for both Android and iOS. You can find installation instructions here. Remember that in current versions of ReactNative linking libraries is not needed anymore (omit linking while installing - it was not written in the instruction)

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-version-number

```
import VersionNumber from 'react-native-version-number';

...

    render() {
        var versionNumber = `${VersionNumber.appVersion}.${VersionNumber.buildVersion}`;

        return (
            <Text style={ styles.versionText }>v. {versionNumber}</Text>
        )
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the thing to fix this nicely and I and happy to see detailed description for doing everything that I needed [react-native-version-check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check)

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
import VersionCheck from 'react-native-version-check';

VersionCheck.needUpdate()
  .then(async res => {
    console.log(res.isNeeded);    // true
    if (res.isNeeded) {
      Linking.openURL(await VersionCheck.getStoreUrl());  // open store if update is needed.
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Expo Framework, you can use `expo-constants` package as documented in https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/.

For me, this is working: grabs the version and description from the `app.json`: https://github.com/marcoXbresciani/TKCompanionApp/blob/0.1.12/screens/about/Version.tsx

So, only one point where to store things.

Answer (score 0):

```
* react-native-cli
import VersionInfo from 'react-native-version-info';

const appVersion = VersionInfo.appVersion;
const buildVersion = VersionInfo.buildVersion;
const bundleIdentifier = VersionInfo.bundleIdentifier


* Expo
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const version = Constants.manifest.version
```

Answer (score -11):

I think the easiest way is to set a version number in App.js just like a variable, and ensure it is global (gettable from the whole app)

```
const version = "1.0.0"
```

and do this i every build

Comment: This does not answersthe original question: how to GET the version that is set in the gradle file.