# How to print application version on older React-native releases

Tags: android, ios, react-native, version

I'm writing react-native application, where I want to display application's current version name in one of the components, let's say in Text.

Before there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240859/how-to-get-a-versionname-in-react-native-app-on-android) about how to get that version, and the answer was to use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info).

Now the problem is, I'm using react-native version 0.35 for my project, because I've got to use [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) as well and CodePush yet doesn't support >=0.36 versions.

**When I want to install react-native-device-info and run:**

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

**I get the following error:**

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.35.0
├── react-native-device-info@0.9.6 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0
```

On react-native-device-info's github page it doesn't say anything about this issue and it seems like it should support react-native 0.35, but it doesn't specify anywhere which version of the module exactly should I use (if this is the reason).

Comment: CodePush do support RN 0.36 https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#supported-react-native-platforms

Comment: Indeed, they have a new release. Thank you for update. Still, there are other components that only work on 0.35 react-native. So the question is still actual.

Comment: If you look at the react-native-device-info's package.json (https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/blob/82e585a515a4169b71a4d57ccd713e65f3c732ec/package.json) there is no peerDeps. So it's another library that causes this errors.

Comment: But after I take out react-native-device-info from dependencies of my project's package.json and execute npm install, it runs smoothly without any error.